Does Leibniz integral rule work on wavefunction?
I am currently reading chapter 1 of the book Introduction Of Quantum Mechanics by David J. Griffiths. In page 14, the book shows the proof that $\frac{d}{dt}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{|\Psi|}^{2}dx = 0$. In the first step of the proof, it just puts the derivative sign inside the integral: $$\frac{d}{dt}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}{|\Psi(x,t)|}^{2}dx = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\partial}{\partial t}{|\Psi (x,t)|}^{2}dx$$
So I wonder whether this operation works on the wave function . As I have observated, the author seem applied Leibniz integral rule ($\Psi$ has continuous partial derivative in setting) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2078844/taking-the-derivative-inside-the-integral-liebniz-rule-for-differentiation-unde.
However, I am not sure whether rule still works when the integration interval is infinity.
So I have searched the post below
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/298458/using-leibniz-integral-rule-on-infinite-region
The post suggests 3 conditions to make the rule valid on infinite intervals.
I can verify the first and third condition. But for the second condition, I cannot think of a function that is always greater than the partial derivative of $\Psi$ against t.
